# loading a stored value into a datetime-local input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datetime

So I have a saved date value in a database.

```
7/31/2018 4:33:00 AM
```

I want to load it's value in to the input, using the value property.

```
<input type="datetime-local" ng-model="meeting.time" "value="meeting.time" />
```

When I change the type to string it's works, but for datetime-local, it shows `mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --` rather than the actual value

Comment: how are you pulling it from the database? Can you cast it with `new Date($scope.meeting.time)`?

Answer (score 0):

firstly you pasted it with a syntax error `"value"="meeting.time"`

if you use ng-model it is not necessary insert value, therefore edit your html code in this

```
<input type="datetime-local" ng-model="meeting.time"/>
```

before load meeting object check if is a date, otherwise convert it into date

like this

```
if(!(meeting.time instanceof Date) && (meeting.time != null)){
  meeting.time = new Date(meeting.time)
}
```